# Zoom Bombing - What specific law is being broken (US and Canada)

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, internet

In "zoom bombing" (teleconference hijacking) what specific law is being broken? Youtube's reporting feature asks to cite the specific laws are being broken? The class I witnessed being zoom bombed was in the US (California). The streamer who did it lives in Canada (British Columbia).

Answer (score 1):

### The [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act)

> The law prohibits accessing a computer without authorization, or in excess of authorization.

Comment: I read about a case where someone exposed himself to a class of school children. What you say will be the case for everyone, but in particular cases other charges could be added.

Comment: Any idea about Canada? If the zoom bomber is in Canada (class in US), would the Canadian law be more relevant/effective?

Comment: @JasonJones Canada has an equivalent law - both apply.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand the notion of "Zoom Bombing", none. There is no authorization required, all you need is the URL. In principle, CFAA could be applicable, but for that law to be applicable, you need to go beyond violating the TOS (e.g. "No profanity"), you have to illegally obtain a password or circumvent password protection.

Comment: "There is no authorization needed to enter your home, just the door being open" - this argument is similarly nonsensical. It doesn't matter how easy it is to access something, when you still need the authority to access it, doing so without said authority is not allowed.

Comment: You should read the pertinent case law, rather than making stuff up. Zoom-bombing invovles an open house, not a closed door.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the door is open, you still aren't allowed into the house.

Comment: Authorization is independent of the technical ability to access a URL.